# Matching location with regular expressions | Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I scraped several articles from a websites. Now I am trying to extract the location of the news. The location are written either capitalized with just the capital of the country (e.g. "BRUSSELS-") or in some cases along with the country (e.g. "BRUSELLS, Belgium-")

This is a sample of the articles:

```
|[<p>Advertisement ,   By  MILAN SCHREUER  and     ALISSA J. RUBIN    OCT. 5, 2016 
 ,  BRUSSELS — A man wounded two police officers with a knife in Brussels around...] 
[<p>Advertisement ,   By   DAVID JOLLY    FEB. 8, 2016 
 ,  KABUL, Afghanistan — A  Taliban  suicide bomber killed at least three people on Monday and wounded]
```

The regular expression I used is this one:

```
text_open = open("Training_News_6.csv")
text_read = text_open.read()
pattern = ("[A-Z]{1,}\w+\s\—")
result = re.findall(pattern,text_read)
print(result)
```

The reason why I used the score sign (-) is because is a recurrent pattern that links to the location.

However, this regular expression manage to extract "BRUSSELS -" but when it comes to "KABUL, Afghanistan -" it only extract the last part, namely "Afghanistan -".
In the second case I would like to extract the whole location: the capital and the country. Any idea?

Comment: Try `r'([A-Z]+)(?:\W+\w+)?\s*—'`. See https://regex101.com/r/ATgIeZ/1

Comment: When I run it it matches only the words capitalised and when the Capitals are followed by a comma and the country I would like to extrac those as well

Comment: Just move the `)` a bit farther: https://regex101.com/r/ATgIeZ/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works perfectly, can you explain me the main changes from your previous one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
([A-Z]+(?:\W+\w+)?)\s*—
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ATgIeZ/2)

**Details**:

- `([A-Z]+(?:\W+\w+)?)` - Capture Group 1 (the contents of which will be returned as the result of `re.findall`) capturing

  - `[A-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII uppercase letters
  - `(?:\W+\w+)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences (due to `?` quantifier) of 1+ non-word chars (`\W+`) and 1+ word chars (`\w+`)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `—` - a `—` symbol

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/udddRQ):

```
import re
rx = r"([A-Z]+(?:\W+\w+)?)\s*—"
s = "|[<p>Advertisement ,   By  MILAN SCHREUER  and     ALISSA J. RUBIN    OCT. 5, 2016 \n,  BRUSSELS — A man wounded two police officers with a knife in Brussels around...] \n[<p>Advertisement ,   By   DAVID JOLLY    FEB. 8, 2016 \n,  KABUL, Afghanistan — A  Taliban  suicide bomber killed at least three people on Mo"
print(re.findall(rx, s)) # => ['BRUSSELS', 'KABUL, Afghanistan']
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is adding `,` and `\s` to your first chars selection, and then stripping all whitespaces and commas from the left.`,[A-Z,\s]{1,}\w+\s\—`
Or even something simpler, like this:`,(.+)\—`. `$1` would be your match, containing extra symbols. Another option which might work: `,\s*([A-Za-z]*[,\s]*[A-Za-z]*)\s\—` or simplified versions: `,\s*([A-Za-z,\s]*)\s\—`. Once again `$1` is your match.